# Drawing a line inside a div with specified coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/u4CBW/

```
$("#ninjaimage1").draggable({
    containment: "#cirlce1",
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        $("#cirlce1").animate({
            top: $(this).offset().top - 60,
            left: $(this).offset().left - 60
        });
    }
});
```

whenever the image is been dragged I want to draw a line between the starting position and the ending position of that image how can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you can have one more image i.e. an image of small dot or have div with height and width of like a dot with your chosen background. When you start the drag, start appending the image (position:absolute) to DOM with the mouse positions i.e. get top and left from mouse positions.

There could be many more ways to accomplish this. But this suggestion comes to my mind and thought to share it.

I know this could be a bit of work.

Check the fiddle:-

http://jsfiddle.net/u4CBW/9/

```
drag: function(e, ui){
             var top = ui.offset.top;
             var left = ui.offset.left;
             var newDot = $("<div class='dot'></div>");
```

There are some css issues. But it is working as your were expecting.

Comment: would u give me an example ?

Comment: @Sora I could be later. I am not on my system right now. I will do this later and send you the fiddle.

Comment: ok fine by me and i will try to make it my own and if i managed to do it i'll post it thank u :)

Comment: but there is a problem with the coordinate you see the image should be the center of the circle and in your example it isn't and when the dots are drown they r not taking the coordinate of the mouse

Comment: @Sora That is the CSS issue. As I said you need to fix CSS for the image so that it should be in the center.

Comment: the image css is fine but in your code you commented two line wish it shouldnt be commented

Comment: @Sora you can uncomment them. My main purpose is to show you example to how to draw line between starting and ending position.